# group by sum in ggplot (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, group-by

I'm trying to get a plot like this:

[image]
I want to get a plot where in each hour interval (hora) plots the sum of nticket for each day (diaSem).

I use this command:

```
ggplot(PorFranjasHyDIas) + geom_line(aes(hora, sum(nTicket), group=hora, color=diaSem))
```

But I get a blank plot.

I got plot from below by switching the main dataset in days, but I couldn't change line thickness and legend title:

```
ggplot() + 
   geom_line(data = Lunes, aes(x = HORA, y = nTickets, group=1, color="red")) +  
   geom_line(data = Martes, aes(x = HORA, y = nTickets, group=1, color="blue"))  + 
   geom_line(data = Miercoles, aes(x = HORA, y = nTickets, group=1, color="green")) +  
   geom_line(data = Jueves, aes(x = HORA, y = nTickets, group=1, color="yellow")) + 
   geom_line(data = Viernes, aes(x = HORA, y = nTickets, group=1, color="orange")) + 
   geom_line(data = Sabado, aes(x = HORA, y = nTickets, group=1, color="gold2")) +  
   xlab('Franja horaria') +  ylab('Num Tickets')
```

**Dataset extract:**

```
diaSem  nTicket esperaMedia hora
J   148 503,59  08:30-9:00
J   589 145,5   09:00-09:30
J   621 124,38  09:30-10:00
J   665 104,96  10:00-10:30
J   624 201,79  10:30-11:00
J   749 248,81  11:00-11:30
J   795 334,07  11:30-12:00
J   812 231,75  12:00-12:30
J   746 183,98  12:30-13:00
J   679 178,06  13:00-13:30
J   424 177,82  13:30-14:00
J   188 583,68  14:00-14:30
J   72  339 14:30-15:00
J   41  815 15:00-15:30
J   45  143,11  15:30-16:00
J   60  310,32  16:00-16:30
J   94  182,48  16:30-17:00
J   165 171,48  17:00-17:30
J   191 263,28  17:30-18:00
J   226 324,7   18:00-18:30
J   165 211,94  18:30-19:00
L   155 539,19  08:30-9:00
L   792 279,39  09:00-09:30
L   694 159,01  09:30-10:00
L   803 141,48  10:00-10:30
L   757 364,21  10:30-11:00
L   875 440,1   11:00-11:30
L   824 500,16  11:30-12:00
L   898 277 12:00-12:30
L   797 264,22  12:30-13:00
L   710 204,12  13:00-13:30
L   460 187,62  13:30-14:00
L   162 333,93  14:00-14:30
L   52  242,96  14:30-15:00
L   64  376,17  15:00-15:30
L   55  65,58   15:30-16:00
L   80  290,25  16:00-16:30
L   90  129,59  16:30-17:00
L   186 229,25  17:00-17:30
L   251 300,66  17:30-18:00
L   293 273,04  18:00-18:30
L   246 174,88  18:30-19:00
M   204 989,21  08:30-9:00
M   705 353,57  09:00-09:30
M   631 255,85  09:30-10:00
M   698 114,52  10:00-10:30
M   713 218,98  10:30-11:00
```

Comment: https://www.ling.upenn.edu/~joseff/rstudy/summer2010_ggplot2_intro.html

Comment: Thanks for adding the data. Why are you using sum, as the counts seem to be unique in each time slot??. `ggplot(PorFranjasHyDIas, aes(hora, nTicket,  group=diaSem, color=diaSem)) + 
  geom_line()` seems to get you close to what you want (i tihnk)

Comment: Maybe post the answer and mark it as correct?

Comment: As user20650 said: ggplot(PorFranjasHyDIas, aes(hora, nTicket, group=diaSem, color=diaSem)) + geom_line(). And it is correct.